# Datefinder Module Stranger behavior on particular string

Tags: python-3.x, datefinder

I have two strings:

```
s1 = 'Agreement dated on March 9, 2007'
s2 = 'Agreement signed on March 9, 2007'
```

I run below code on the string

```
import datefinder
matches =datefinder.find_dates(s1) ## or s2
for match in matches:
       print (match)
```

`s2` gives me desired result but `s1` doesn't as it contains the word dated.

P.S. I have used datefinder as I had multiple date formats and hence need to write multiple regex. This worked well just for this exception

Any idea why this strange behavior?

Comment: It could be a bug.